# Using Cauchy's integral formula for several points

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate $$\int_{C} \frac{z^{3}}{z^{4} -3}dx$$, if $C$ is positive oriented circle $ |z| =3$.

I was instantly thinking of using Cauchy's integral formula, since $\frac{z^{3}}{z^{4} -1}$ is not holomorfic only in zeros of denominator (and all four of them belong to $C$), but I am not sure how to use it properly beacuse I only came across examples where one zero is in the observed circle.

Comment: The residue theorem states that the value of the integral is $$\int_C f(z)dz = 2\pi i\sum \text{Res}{(f(z))}$$

Comment: Enclose each pole with 1 sufficiently small circle that centered at these poles, then $\int_C$ equals sum of $\int$ over these circles. OR, consider the so-called "multiple-keyholed" contour.

Comment: $|z|\ne 3$ for the zeros of the denominator. It would be that if your denominator would be $z^4-3^4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cauchy's integral formula directly by taking advantage of the fact that the sum of all residues is $0$. This includes the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity):

Let $f(z) = \frac{z^{3}}{z^{4} -3}$. Since there is no further singularity outside of $C$, you have
$$\int_{C} \frac{z^{3}}{z^{4} -3}dz =- 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z)$$

Calculating this residue is straight forward:
\begin{eqnarray*} \operatorname{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z)
& = &  -\operatorname{Res}_{w=0}\frac{1}{w^2}f\left(\frac{1}{w} \right) \\
& = & -\operatorname{Res}_{w=0}\frac{1}{w^2}\frac{ \frac{1}{w^3}}{\frac{1}{w^4}-3} \\
& = & -\operatorname{Res}_{w=0}\frac{1}{w}\frac{ 1}{1-3w^4}\\
& = & -1
\end{eqnarray*}
Putting all together gives

$$\int_{C} \frac{z^{3}}{z^{4} -3}dz = -2\pi i\left( \operatorname{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z) \right) = 2\pi i$$